# pg_dump and friends: backup and restore using tablespace

Tags: postgresql

Given a database dump how to specify a tablespace to be used by all tables during restore? The database has multiple tablespaces used by its table. Old  tablespaces should be ignored (they are not relevant on new computer) and all tablespaces my by replaced by a new one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- dump with "--no-tablespaces" parameter to have tablespaces-free dump - but you can also use the same parameter on pg_restore if you cannot change dump commands
- set global parameter "default_tablespace" on target DB to what is needed for restore (for example by using `alter database xxxxx set DEFAULT_TABLESPACE='xxx'`)
- run all pg_restore tasks
- if necessary reset default_tablespace to original value

Comment: this works. another solution is to set tablespace for entire database.